# how to do autocomplete="off" at form level in JSF

Tags: jsf

how to do autocomplete="off" at form level in JSF?

Answer (score 13):

The best and easiest way of doing this is this:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <f:passThroughAttribute name="autocomplete" value="off"/>
    ...
</h:form>
```

Don't forget to add `xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"` to your `head` attribite if you don't have already.

**Why?**

1. Because if you have an ajax event somewhere in your page that needs to update/render your form, it will not loose the `autocomplete` attribute.
2. Because it looks sexy (JS way looks ugly).

**Tip:** You can use `f:passThroughAttribute` for every JSF element which does not have any specific attribute of newer HTML specifications.

Comment: Sadly this only works with JSF 2.2. Still the best solution by far, if supported.

Comment: I tested this solution on JSF version 2.3 and it works

Answer (score 10):

A real quick solution with Javascript would be (assuming you have got jQuery loaded):

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#form").attr("autocomplete", "off");
    });
</script>
```

If you want to stay with vanilla Javascript, you can do:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        document.getElementById("form").setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
    });
</script>
```

Note: For the second solution make sure your browser is covered here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded#Browser_compatibility 
If not you might be better off using the first solution.

Comment: While using jQuery, if your form id contains ':' character you'll get unsupported pseudo error. You can use $(document.getElementById( 'parentElement:formElement').attr("autocomplete", "off"); if this is the case. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077280/uncaught-error-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression-unsupported-pseudo for details

Comment: best viable solution for me. using jsf 2.0