# Disable web browser password save

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jboss

I have a simple Login page made with JSF 2.0. Usually in every login page the web browser proposes to the user to save his username a password.

I saw in Oracle's web site where user must authenticate that when I enter my username and password the browser do not ask me do I want to save my username and password. Maybe there is a way to disable this from the code of the login page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You basically need to add `autocomplete="off"` attribute to the HTML `<form>` element. However, this attribute is not supported on the `<h:form>`. It's only supported on the individual `<h:inputText>` and `<h:inputSecret>` components.

So, this should do:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{auth.username}" required="true" autocomplete="off" />
    <h:inputSecret value="#{auth.password}" required="true" autocomplete="off" />
    <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{auth.login}" />
    <h:messages />
</h:form>
```

The new `autocomplete` attribute on `<h:form>` is scheduled for JSF 2.2. See also [JSF spec issue 418](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-418).

Or, if you're using container managed login with `j_security_check` which requires a plain vanilla HTML `<form>` anyway, then just add it in there:

```
<form action="j_security_check" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="j_username" />
    <input type="password" name="j_password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

#### See also:

- [`<h:inputText>` tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/inputText.html) (mentions `autocomplete` attribute)
- [`<h:inputSecret>` tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/inputSecret.html) (mentions `autocomplete` attribute)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Jquery to prevent the autocomplete option. So, we no need to have for the individual fields.

```
<script>
$(function(){
$("#formID").attr("autocomplete", "off");
});
</script>
```

[how to do autocomplete="off" at form level in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211442/how-to-do-autocomplete-off-at-form-level-in-jsf)

Answer (score -2):

If adding "autocomplete" not work, you can try this trick. You should place a fake "inputText" after real one with this style:

```
<p:inputText style="display: none;"/>
```

Comment: Did you test it? It hide whole text field

Comment: Does this not hide entire text field?

Comment: Absolutely yes, I tested it.