# JSF SelectOneMenu Browser Back Button

Tags: jsf, browser-cache, back-button, selectonemenu

I have a problem where I am using a SelectOneMenu for navigation:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{navigator.outcome}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select item.." />
    <f:selectItems value="#{navigator.menuItems}" />
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{navigator.navigate}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

This works fine except when I navigate back it doesnt display "Select Item.."

The navigator bean is request scoped (I've tried view scoped as well).
I've disabled caching using a WebFilter.

Comment: Since you haven't cached the page, when you go back in your browser, your `navigator` managed bean must be recreated, have you tried to debug this behavior as well?

Comment: Yup the bean is recreated...I'm not sure why the browser isnt updating. Not sure how to debug that.

Comment: When the bean is recreated, is `navigator.menuItems` filled?

Comment: I think this is a problem with browser caching select options. Apparently adding autocomplete=off fixes this but not sure if I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn autocomplete off at the form level.
With JSF 2.1 you cannot do this.

Either wait until JSF 2.2 or uses omnifaces:

See link:
[how to do autocomplete="off" at form level in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211442/how-to-do-autocomplete-off-at-form-level-in-jsf)