# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo:

Tags: javascript, jsf

i have an txtBox and its id is : beginDateTxt

but jsf makes it `j_idt8:beginDateTxt`

in jquery i try to reach it like that

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(function() {
                    $("#j_idt8:beginDateTxt").mobiscroll().date({
                       theme: 'android-ics light', mode:'scroller', display: 'bottom'
                    });
                });

            });
   </script>
```

but i get below error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: beginDateTxt

why?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You could try

```
$(document.getElementById('j_idt8:beginDateTxt')).mobiscroll().date({theme: 'android-ics light', mode:'scroller', display: 'bottom'});
```

In general jQuery uses something like CSS selectors in its `$()` function. In a CSS selector the `:` denotes a pseudo-class. However, in your case the `:` is just a part of the id.

If you use the generic `getElementById()`, the argument is *not* decomposed, but seen as an ID altogether. So by using `getElementById()` and wrapping the result with `$()` you can circumvent this "misunderstanding".

In general, however, I think it would be better to change the namespacing scheme in your JSF.

**EDIT**

The [jQuery documentation on selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) states that you should escape special characters by the use of `\\`:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with `id="foo.bar"`, can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`.

This will lead to the answer already given by Daniel, which in my opinion is superior to the answer given above. The explanation, however, remains valid.

```
$("#j_idt8\\:beginDateTxt").mobiscroll().date({theme: 'android-ics light', mode:'scroller', display: 'bottom'});
```

Comment: I thought we are using jQuery selector so we don't use getElementById

Comment: @BobSort The problem here was, that the id included a `:`, which made jQuery think a pseudo class is used and in the result fail. To circumvent I used `getElementById()`, which interprets its argument just as a string.

Comment: it works. however, I think one of the benefits of using jquery is that we don't have to use getelementbyid. instead of building a jquery node out of the return of d.getelem...() , a real solution would be escaping correctly the string that goes in the jquery selector.

Comment: I had completely forgotten about escaping the colon (:). I was using the id verbatim from the code and slowly going mad. thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 33):

If you want to use jQuery id selector you need to escape the `:` with `\` and then to escape the `\` (double escape)

Here:

```
$(function() {
    $("#j_idt8\\:beginDateTxt").mobiscroll().date({
        theme: 'android-ics light',
        mode:'scroller', display: 'bottom'
    });
});
```

Comment: I like this one better. Just answers the question lol.