# How to prevent unwanted autofills on JSF input tags

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

First of all, I develop a web application and I use **JSF 2.2.6**.

When **user-name** and **password** is saved with user permission in "Login" page by Chrome or Firefox, other empty **h:inputText** and **h:inputSecret** in "Admin Panel" page are **autofilled** with these saved information (name and password in login process).

I use template feature of JSF 2.x to design my pages. I use the same form (id=mainForm) in this template for all my pages. However, ids of input elements of login page are different from ids of input elements in "Admin Panel" page.

After I found the question and answer - [Unwanted Autofills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172036/unwanted-autofills) , I began to use **"autocomplete='off'"** for inputs in "Admin Panel". However, nothing changes.

Why does it work properly? How can I handle this problem. I want to display h:inputText and h:inputSecret tags in Admin Panel with no initial record as they actually have.

All feedbacks appreciated!

Login Page;

```
   <ui:composition template="...">
        <ui:define name="headContent">
            <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="loginPage.css" />
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="content">
            <div id="loginArea">
                <h:inputText id="nameInput" class="nameInput" value="#{loginFacade.loginName}" />
                <h:inputSecret id="passInput" class="passInput" value="#{loginFacade.loginPass}" />
                <h:commandButton id="..." class="sendInput" image="..." 
                            binding="..." action="..." />
                <h:messages class="errorMessage" layout="table" />
                <p:defaultCommand target="sendInput" />
            </div>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

Admin Panel page;

```
  ...
        <td>
            <span jsfc="h:outputLabel" value="#{msgs['adminPanel.userName']}"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input jsfc="h:inputText" id="usrDetUsrName" class="usrDetLbl" value="#{adminPanelFacade.tempUsr.USER_NAME}" disabled="#{adminPanelFacade.newRecFlag}" autocomplete="off"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="usrDetTblRow">
        <td>
            <span jsfc="h:outputLabel" value="#{msgs['adminPanel.password']}"></span>
        </td>
         <td>
            <input jsfc="h:inputSecret" id="usrDetPass" class="usrDetLbl" redisplay="true" value="#{adminPanelFacade.tempUsr.PASSWORD}" autocomplete="off"/>
        </td> 
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`Google Chrome and IE (v11 onwards)` don't respect `autocomplete=off` in favour of usability of saving passwords for any website.

They change the property `autocomplete=off` to true.
You would need to develop a custom script that changes the property back to "Off"

You can add a reset function to add the `autocomplete "off"` back in  the form using below script,

```
function setAutocomplete()
{
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') >= 0) 
{
setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById('myForm').setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off'); 
}, 100);
}
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but there was nothing changed. I saw "autocomplete=off" attribute on form or input tag (based on which tag I set) in generated HTML. However, related form or input element continued containing saved information(name and password). I also tried OmniFaces Html5RenderKit that was offered by BalusC in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211442/how-to-do-autocomplete-off-at-form-level-in-jsf. Although, "autocomplete=off" is contained in generated HTML, there was nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me in bothe Fire fox and chrome Browsers , You can use 2 empty input tags:

```
<input name="dummyinput" id="dummyinput" type="text" /> 

<input name="dummypassword" type="password" id="dummypassword" />
```

before your  name input (h:inputText) , and add another empty input password field say
`<input id=dummypassword2" name=dummypassword2" type="password" />`  after your password field (h:inputSecret) , Login credentials wont be stored.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me (autocomplete='off' didn't). You can also add style="display: none" to these 2 inputs so they don't even show to the user