# How to do autocomplete=“off” for p:inputText?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am doing a project using primefaces.

In that I am using user login page.

My problem is that, when i enter the text on `p:inputText` the previous value is appeared on the `p:inputText`.

I used `autocomplete=“off”` in `p:inputText` and I cleared my Mozilla browser history on every login but still its not working well.

**Code:**

```
<h:form>

 <p:inputText id="userName" autocomplete="off" value="...">
      <p:ajax event="focus" listener="..." update="infoMessage"/>
 </p:inputText>

 <p:watermark for="userName" value="..." id="userLabelWaterMarkId"/>

 <p:password id="password" autocomplete="off"  value="....">
      <p:ajax event="focus" listener="....." update="infoMessage"/>
 </p:password>   

 <p:watermark for="password" value="..." id="pwddWaterMarkId"/>

</h:form>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Whats your bean scope ?

Comment: session is my bean scope.@ jNick

Comment: If you don't care about disabling `autocomplete` for the whole `<h:form>` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38837254/1980659 .

Answer (score 1):

First check that your session scoped bean isn't storing the value.

Next you need to clear your Mozilla browser cache, not the history. If the browser has already cached the form data it will continue to auto fill it in and ignore your `autocomplete=“off”` attribute. This is a feature / behavior that acts differently across various browsers. For example, Internet explorer may honor your `autocomplete=“off”` attribute ignoring its own cache, where as Mozilla Firefox may not. This result could very depending on the version of the browser as well (ex. IE 8 vs IE9)

Comment: Yes right,in internet explore there ll not be come previous entered values on that p:inputText field.only problem is in Mozilla cache. i ll check it.thankq

Comment: I cleared my Mozilla cache too but still its not working. that previous entered values still there appear when click on p:inputText